# A fast way to build a nice UI for a grails app?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I'm starting a fairly complex grails app but am a bit slow hand-coding nice user interface pages directly in CSS/HTML.  Several people have recommended IntelliJ for the grails app development, and I plan to use mostly grails scaffolding for the admin portion of the site.

Can you recommend an approach or tools for building a nice UI fairly fast?

Thanks

P.S.  Eventually I plan to build "skinnier" mobile version as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach might be to continue to use the grails sitemesh main.gsp and just concentrate on your functionality using the scaffold-ed pages as examples.  Once you are ready to tackle the style aspect you can deviate from the grails main.gsp template and create your own tailored for your look and feel.

If your complexity includes a fairly custom UI, I don't think your going to get a free lunch.  You'll have to break down and code the UI.

I'm currently using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) coupled with [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) to get some fairly sophisticated grid / tree behavior in my UI with not too much html coding. I'm also using the jQuery UI Layout Plugin to manage pane layout and make my app look/feel more like an app rather than a page.  Grails plays real nice with the ajax needs of jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out jqGrid and the jQuery UI Layout Plugin.  Do you know if these can be themed with jQuery UI as well? Also, can I ask if you have a preferred IDE for grails and other JS/CSS/HTML work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the jqGrid takes on the JQuery theming. Not sure on the Layout as I really use it for dividing up the panes on the page. IDE: Intellij, I use it and recommend it specifically for Grails but it really has nice JS/CSS/HTML support as well.